# python pandas reshape csv to get list of items within category

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm trying to reshape a csv to get items within an order as a list.

I have something like the top table and want to get the bottom table. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this Julia,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'mmddyyyy':['1/22/17']*5,
                   'customer_id':[1,1,2,2,2],
                   'order_id':[67,67,50,51,51],
                  'item_id':['hat','hat','pants','hat','pants']})

df
```

Output:

```
   customer_id item_id mmddyyyy  order_id
0            1     hat  1/22/17        67
1            1     hat  1/22/17        67
2            2   pants  1/22/17        50
3            2     hat  1/22/17        51
4            2   pants  1/22/17        51
```

Now, let's run `groupby` with `apply` and `list` then `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby(['mmddyyyy','customer_id','order_id'])['item_id']\
  .apply(list).reset_index()
```

Output result df:

```
  mmddyyyy  customer_id  order_id       item_id
0  1/22/17            1        67    [hat, hat]
1  1/22/17            2        50       [pants]
2  1/22/17            2        51  [hat, pants]
```

Comment: Looks like a winning strategy to me!

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it.

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe_top = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
dataframe_bottom = dataframe_top.groupby('order_id').agg({
    'mmddyyyy': 'first',
    'customer_id': 'first',
    'item_id': lambda x: list(x)
}).reset_index()
```

Alternatively, the following should also work:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe_top = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
dataframe_bottom = dataframe_top\
    .groupby(['mmddyyyy', 'customer_id', 'order_id'])\
    .apply(list)[['item_id']]\
    .reset_index()
```

In both cases, we are grouping by the `order_id`, and applying the function `list` to the column `item_id`. In the second case, grouping by the first three columns does not change the row structure of the resulting table, because all order ids have the same `mmddyyyy` and `customer_id` anyway.

See the following for the `groupby` method:
https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_apply_operations_to_groups.html

See the following for the `agg` method. (A method of the `groupby` object, i.e. it can only be added to the end of a `groupby` method)
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html
(Scroll down to `In [20]:` and `In [21]:` at the link.)

EDIT: Final note: Are you sure this is what you want? This looks more like an intermediate step to some ultimate goal. I would bet that your ultimate goal does not actually require this transformation, but some other `groupby` functionality. Consider asking about how to achieve your final goal instead.